# How to optimize query with several conditions and grouping?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table like this:

[image]

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_all_hour_1` (
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `id_station` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_begin` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `time_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_coltype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`id_station`,`time_begin`,`area_type`,`id_coltype`),
  KEY `NewIndex1` (`date`,`time_begin`,`id_coltype`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `area_type` can have up to 10 distinct values.
The `id_coltype` can be up to 2000 distinct values.

The size of the table is about 10 million rows.

I need a query to get value of all `id_coltype` in all `area_type` with 2 time range (so I can compare this range to previous range).

Query:

```
SELECT  
  CONCAT_WS('-', 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-04-30' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(88),data_value,0)),0),''), 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-04-30' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(89),data_value,0)),0),''), 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-04-30' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(90),data_value,0)),0),''), 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-12-31' AND '2016-02-29' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(88),data_value,0)),0),''), 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-12-31' AND '2016-02-29' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(89),data_value,0)),0),''), 
      COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-12-31' AND '2016-02-29' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(90),data_value,0)),0),'') 
  ) AS '86',  
  id_station,
  area_type,
  IFNULL(id_station,'sum_result') AS 'key'
FROM report_all_hour_1
WHERE id_station IN(493,494,495,496,517,960,961,962,963,964,965,518,1054,1499)
    AND `date` BETWEEN '2015-12-31'
    AND '2016-04-30'
    AND time_begin >= '09:00:00'
    AND time_begin < '22:00:00'
GROUP BY area_type, id_station WITH ROLLUP
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',COALESCE(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102),data_value, 0)),''), COALESCE(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102),data_value, 0)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,`date`,NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,WEEK(`date`),NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,MONTH(`date`),NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,`date`,NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,WEEK(`date`),NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,MONTH(`date`),NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,`id_station`,NULL)),''), COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(102) AND data_value > 0,`id_station`,NULL)),'') ) AS '159',
  CONCAT(IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(928),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(260),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(376),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(492),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(618),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(734),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(259),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(375),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(491),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(617),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(733),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(928),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(260),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(376),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(492),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(618),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(734),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(259),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(375),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(491),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(617),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(733),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),'-', IFNULL(SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0) ) AS '112',
  CONCAT_WS('-', COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(34),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(35),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(36),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(37),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(38),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(39),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(40),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(41),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(42),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(43),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(46),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(44),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(47),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(48),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(45),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(49),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(169),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(169),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(262),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(378),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(494),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(620),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(736),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(262),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(378),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(494),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(620),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(736),data_value,0)),0),'') ) AS '97',
  CONCAT_WS('-', COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(17),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(18),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(19),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(20),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(21),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(22),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(23),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(24),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(25),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(26),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(27),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(28),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(29),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(30),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(31),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(32),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(17),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(18),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(19),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(20),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(21),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(22),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(23),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(24),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(25),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(26),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(27),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(28),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(29),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(30),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(31),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(32),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value, 0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),''), COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(33),data_value,0)),0),'') ) AS '93',
  CONCAT( COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00',(IF(id_coltype=63,data_value*0,0)+ IF(id_coltype=64,data_value*1,0)+IF(id_coltype=65,data_value*2,0)+IF(id_coltype=66,data_value*3,0)+IF(id_coltype=67,data_value*4,0)+IF(id_coltype=68,data_value*5,0)+IF(id_coltype=69,data_value*6,0)+IF(id_coltype=70,data_value*7,0)+IF(id_coltype=71,data_value*8,0)+IF(id_coltype=72,data_value*9,0)),0)),0),'') ,'-', COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2015-02-04' AND '2017-02-25' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72),data_value,0)),0),'') ,'-', COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00',(IF(id_coltype=63,data_value*0,0)+ IF(id_coltype=64,data_value*1,0)+IF(id_coltype=65,data_value*2,0)+IF(id_coltype=66,data_value*3,0)+IF(id_coltype=67,data_value*4,0)+IF(id_coltype=68,data_value*5,0)+IF(id_coltype=69,data_value*6,0)+IF(id_coltype=70,data_value*7,0)+IF(id_coltype=71,data_value*8,0)+IF(id_coltype=72,data_value*9,0)),0)),0),'') ,'-', COALESCE(IFNULL(SUM( IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12' AND '2015-02-03' AND time_begin >= '09:00:00' AND time_begin < '22:00:00' AND id_coltype IN(63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72),data_value,0)),0),'') ) AS '7'
FROM report_all_hour_1
WHERE id_station IN(493,494,495,496,517,960,961,962,963,964,965,518,1054,1499)
    AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-01-12'
    AND '2017-02-25'
    AND time_begin >= '09:00:00'
    AND time_begin < '22:00:00'
GROUP BY area_type, id_station WITH ROLLUP
```

EXPLAIN: 
[image]

The problem is slow performance, it's take 4 minutes to get what I need. Is there anyway to improve this query?

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/272479/1

Comment: Indexing primary and foraign key can help you.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: KEY: date-id_station-time_begin-area_type-id_coltype
index: date-id_station-id_coltype

but I think index is not helpful in this case because the number of rows is included all records I needed for this query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/272479/1

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially 3 filters in the `WHERE`.  Which is more selective?  How selective?  That is, what percentage of the table would be selected with each of these:

```
id_station IN (...)
date BETWEEN ...
time_begin ...
```

Currently, you only use `date` for filtering, since that is at the start of both indexes.

If either of the other two fields (`id_station` or `time_begin`) is sufficiently selective, add an index on that column:

```
INDEX(id_station, date)
INDEX(time_begin)
```

(There is no use adding more columns to either.)

If you change the constants from run to run, then add both of those indexes; either one might work some of the time.

Do you always pick a date range that is exactly on month boundaries?  (Apparently not, since you start with 12-31?)  If you do, then we can talk about Summary tables.

Comment: your index worked very with only 1 select field, but when I select many fields(Query 2 I just added above) then it's not working. very slow performance

Comment: indexes is not work when I use select with many condition there? because I use a lot of IF condition in select

Comment: The `iF` conditions in `SELECT` are only a minor slowdown.

Comment: Indexes work best with `=` tests.  You have essentially 3 "range" tests.  The problem is that you can only use one of them.  Imagine looking up my name knowing only my initials; that essentially 2 range tests:  `WHERE last>='J' and last<'K' AND first>='R' and first<'S'`.  The best index can only search by one or the other of `last` or `first`.

Comment: More discussion in my [_Index Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)

Comment: do you have any ideas to make another query? I need a query to select and compare data of 2 date ranges, this table contain million(can billion rows in the future)

Comment: @sontd - Before I tackle the 2-date-range question, please see how fast selecting _one_ date range is, with two indexes:  `(date, ...)` and `(id_station, date)`.  And do `EXPLAIN` to see which index the Optimizer chooses.  If the sum of those two times is significantly better than the times we have gotten so far, then I have a plan.